# Utilizando função e arquivo de cabeçalho (header)

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa simples porém utilizando arquivo de cabeçalho .h (header) e uma função olá mundo, mas estou com a seguinte mensagem de alerta: **Undefined reference to 'imprime'**. Pedi para outra pessoa testar e disse que deu certo o que pode ser ainda?

Segue código:

```
=== Arquivo MainCodeCount.c ==

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LibCodeCount.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    imprime();

    return 0;
}


=== Arquivo CodeCount.c ===

#include <stdio.h>
#include "LibCodeCount.h"

void imprime()
{
    printf("Ola mundo!\n");
}


=== Arquivo CodeCount.h (header) ==

void imprime();
```

Comment: Agradeço atenção senhores, mas resolvi da seguinte maneira: Apenas configurei o gcc no path do windows e os comandos:
gcc -c MainCodeCount.c
gcc -c LibCodeCount.c

depois,

gcc -o HELLO MainCodeCount.o LibCodeCount.o

Executei o Hello.exe e foi.

Comment: Se você resolveu seu problema dessa forma, melhor colocar como uma **resposta** ao invés de um comentário. Assim fica mais fácil saber o que voc6e fez para resolver seu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é meramente que você compilou apenas um arquivo, o `MainCodeCount.c` e deixou o `CodeCount.c` de fora. Assim sendo não há ninguém definindo a função a função `imprime()` na etapa de linking e o erro ocorre:

> undefined reference to `imprime()`

A correção é compilar todos os seus arquivos:

```
gcc -c MainCodeCount.c                            (MainCodeCount.c -> MainCodeCount.o)
gcc -c LibCodeCount.c                             (LibCodeCount.c -> LibCodeCount.o)
gcc -o Hello MainCodeCount.o LibCodeCount.o       (*.o -> Hello.exe)
```

---

Outra coisa que falta no seu código mas que da forma que está não vai lhe causar nenhum problema são os *header guards*. Em todo arquivo de cabeçalho use o seguinte:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

// seu código aqui

#endif
```

Ou:

```
#pragma once

// seu código aqui
```

O objetivo é que o cabeçalho seja processado apenas uma vez por unidade de compilação, mesmo se incluído mais de uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Tente referenciar em todos os arquivos

```
#include "CodeCount.h"
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente em CodeCount.h, mudar o código para:

```
#ifndef __CODECOUNT_H__
#define __CODECOUNT_H__

void imprime();

#endif
```

Em teoria a sua mensagem de erro não tem a ver com referências duplicadas, mas estou sem outras ideias do que pode ser agora.

Comment: Sorry, 
mas é LibCodeCount.c e .h

Comment: Sem problemas. Se possível, edite a pergunta para mostrar o nome certo do arquivo.

Comment: Editei a resposta com outra possível solução.