# include library em C é obrigatório?

Tags: c, include

Me deparei com a seguinte situação:

> Ubuntu 16.01
>
> gcc --version
>
> gcc (GCC) 6.3.0
>   Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

`test.c`

```
main() {
    printf("Hello Word.\n");
    printf("pow function : %f \n", pow(10,2));
}
```

Use este comando para compilar:

```
gcc -std=c11  test.c -o test

test.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main() {
 ^~~~
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("Hello Word.\n");
   ^~~~~~
test.c:4:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
test.c:4:3: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
test.c:5:35: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pow’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   printf("powf function : %d \n", pow(10,2));
                                   ^~~
test.c:5:35: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘pow’
test.c:5:35: note: include ‘<math.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘pow’
```

E executei o arquivo gerado:

```
./test

Hello Word.
pow function : 100.000000
```

Pergunto: eu sou obrigado a fazer o  `#include <stdio.h>` e `#include <math.h>` ? isso vale para todas [standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)?

---

Arquivo alterado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello Word.\n");
    printf("powf function : %f \n", pow(10,2));
    return 0;
 }
```

Comando para compilar  (neste caso não tem warnings):

```
gcc -std=c11  test.c -o test
```

Saida:

```
./test

Hello Word.
pow function : 100.000000
```

Nos dois casos a saída é a mesma.

[image: im1]
[image: img2]

Answer (score 7):

Se você usa algo dessa biblioteca então tem que usar sim.

Dependendo do compilador e suas configurações é possível que ache as funções para *linkar*.

Quando gera *warning* significa que seu código está errado, mas ele consegue gerar um executável. Se vai funcionar é uma questão de coincidência. Pode funcionar ou não dependendo da operação e do resultado desejado.

Todo programador profissional trata *warnings* como se fossem erro, porque eles são erros. Só não impedem a compilação.

Uma coisa que eu sempre falo e poucos escutam é que estar certo e funcionar são coisas muito distintas. O certo é o que se deseja. O que funciona é algo circunstancial ou coincidente. Funciona, mas nada garante que continuará assim em todas situações. Um erros que programadores iniciantes cometem, e alguns são iniciantes mesmo depois de décadas fazendo isto, é testar ver que deu o que ele queria ver e achar que está certo. Só está certo o que pode ser provado que acontece o desejado em todas situações possíveis, inclusive as pouco prováveis que aconteçam.

Claro que provar que tudo está certo o tempo todo é quase inviável. Por isso softwares possuem *bugs*. Você prova até certo ponto. O problema é que se provar apenas em uma situação a chance do código ter um *bug* pode ser superior a 50%. Se provar as coisas fáceis e deixas só o que é difícil sem provas, ou uma ou outra coisa que não pensou e for raro, aí a chance de um *bug* fica menor que 1%.

Então é obrigatório colocar o `include`, mesmo que não impeça a compilação em uma situações específica.

[Note que eu um compilador configurado idealmente isto daria erro](http://ideone.com/pcZmBc)  e nem compilaria.

Se quer saber mais sobre o `include` já tem uma pergunta sobre o assunto: [Como funciona a diretiva "#include"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101). Também: [Utilizando função e arquivo de cabeçalho (header)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11360/101).

Answer (score 5):

## Pra que serve o `#include`?

O `#include` é uma diretiva de preprocessador, isto é, uma transformação do texto do programa que ocorre antes da análise sintática propriamente dita. Ela recebe um nome de arquivo como parâmetro e substitui a si mesma pelo texto do arquivo mencionado: assim, uma linha desta forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Vai ser substituída pelo conteúdo do arquivo `stdio.h` em um diretório específico da sua máquina (no caso do Ubuntu, provavelmente é `/usr/local/include/`, mas pode ser diferente).

Naturalmente, existem muitas maneiras de se aproveitar este mecanismo, mas o modo padrão de se utilizá-lo é incluir os chamados *arquivos de cabeçalho* (no inglês *header files*, donde a sua extensão padrão `.h`). Estes são arquivos em linguagem C, mas que contêm apenas:

- Definições de macros de pré-processador (via `#define` e outros mecanismos afins, por exemplo, a definição de `NULL` em `stddef.h`);
- Definições de tipos (por exemplo, o tipo `FILE *` definido em `stdio.h` ou `struct tm` em `time.h`);
- Declarações de variáveis globais, como `errno` em `errno.h`;
- *Declarações* de funções, onde o arquivo informa ao compilador que uma função com determinado nome existe, e quais parâmetros ela recebe e qual o tipo do valore que retornam;
- Inclusões de *outros* cabeçalhos nos quais os cabeçalhos dependem.

## E no meu caso concreto?

No seu caso, você pode ver que utilizou duas funções: [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) e [`pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/). As declarações das funções são as seguintes:

```
int printf(const char * format, ...);
double pow(double base, double exponent);
```

Quando o compilador encontra uma invocação de função que não foi previamente declarada, ele emite um aviso reclamando e assume que a função retorna `int` e recebe um número indeterminado de parâmetros.  No caso das duas funções acima, elas recebem e retornam tipos primitivos, e portanto a invocação destas funções calha de funcionar, embora a verificação de tipos fique prejudicada.

Agora, se em vez de `printf()` você tentasse usar [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/), que recebe como primeiro parâmetro um *stream* tipo `FILE *`, você precisaria passar o *stream* correto (`stdout` para que a `fprintf()` reproduza os efeitos da `printf()`), que é declarado no cabeçalho `stdio.h`.  Ao compilar este código, você receberia um erro de `undefined symbol 'stdout'` e a compilação pararia.

## Sistema de tipos

Uma outra desvantagem de invocar funções que não foram previamente declaradas é que isso desativa a verificação de tipos para a invocação da função. Você pode acabar passando um parâmetro de um tipo errado para a função (por exemplo, passando um inteiro no lugar da *string* de formatação para `printf()`) e o compilador não vai detectar o problema.

Aí neste momento você tem um programa que compilou, mas vai ter algum comportamento estranho quando você executar aquela função (pode gerar um erro de proteção ou pior: continuar executando).

## TL;DR

Se você invoca funções da biblioteca padrão C sem carregar os cabeçalhos correspondentes, a invocação *pode* funcionar se a função em questão não pedir como parâmetro ou retornar nenhum valor, tipo ou global definida no cabeçalho. Conforme os programas vão aumentando de complexidade, a probabilidade de isso acontecer tende a zero.

Answer (score 2):

Resumidamente, o macro `#include` copia todo o conteúdo de uma header file para uma outra header file ou source file. Muitas pessoas confundem os arquivos standard de C com a linguagem C em si, e isso é um erro grave. C é somente a linguagem em si, o conjunto de regras sintáticas e keywords que compõem um programa. A biblioteca standard de C é um trabalho construído sobre as bases fundamentais da linguagem.

Portanto, sim, é necessário o acréscimo de `#include` em todos os arquivos que façam uso de funções, macros, variáveis e estruturas de dados de um outro arquivo em C.

Extra: Alguns compiladores, como GCC, conseguem detectar quando você faz uso de uma função da biblioteca padrão de C. Em GCC, por exemplo, se você fizer uso da função `printf`, o compilador reconhece imediatamente a função, inclui implicitamente a header file `stdio` e gera um aviso. Não é bom, tampouco sustentável, fazer uso dessa função, portanto sempre inclua as header files necessárias, até mesmo se elas forem parte do standard de C.